# Multi-Threaded Write in multiple files

Tags: c

I want to create a c code where I have to create Multiple Files using Multiple thread.
f = number of files to create,
t = number of threads
each output file should be named "`file_<id>.bin`" where `<id>` is a unique integer from 0 to (f-1) such that each of t threads creates approximately f/t of the files.

I am unable to approach this question using open(), close(), read() and write() functions of Linux.

I have written the code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int isDirectoryExists(const char *path);
void *func(void *ptr);
int file;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pthread_t thread1;
        int  p;
        p=1;
        int f=atoi(argv[2]);
        if (isDirectoryExists(argv[1]))
        {
                printf("Directory exists at path '%s'\n", argv[1]);
                printf("Creating a new file at the Directory using Open Function");
                for(int i = 1; i<=f; i++)
                {
                        int number = i;
                        char index[20];
                        sprintf(index, "%d", number);
                        printf("\nThe number bring printed as the index of the file is:- %s", index);
                        char str[] = "unsorted_";
                        char str1[] = ".bin";
                        strcpy(str,index);
                        strcpy(str,str1);
                        file=open(str, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR , 0666);
                        printf("file = %d/n", file);
                        if (file ==-1)
                        {
                                printf("Error Number % d\n", errno);
                                perror("Program");
                        }

                pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func, (void *)&p);
                pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
                close(file);
                }
        return 0;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Directory does not exists at path '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        }
}

void *func(void *ptr)
{
        int *num;
        int ret = -1;
        num = (int *)ptr;
        char buf[4] = {0};
        printf("%d\n", *num);
        printf("%d", *num);
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof (buf));
        snprintf(buf, sizeof *num, "%d", *num);
        ret = write(file, buf, strlen(buf));
        if (ret < 0)
        printf("ret is %d, errno %d\n", ret, errno);

        return 0;
}

int isDirectoryExists(const char *path)
{
      struct stat stats;
      stat(path, &stats);
      if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode))
        return 1;
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the specific error or incorrect behaviour that your program has.

Comment: I am facing issues with spawning multithreads. Also, it did not create any files

Comment: "facing issues" is not a clear description. What issues? Please be specific.

Comment: @parthparashar In my testing, it does create files, but all of them are named `.bin`, because strcpy replaces the value in str with the value in str1.

Comment: So... Give your files unique names instead of reusing ".bin" for all of them? You initialize `str` with one value, then fill it with a different value and immediately again fill it with yet another. Doesn't make any sense to do that. And creating a thread immediately followed by joining it means you might as well not bother with threads.

Comment: Are you doing this in an attempt to increase read/write speed? Note that there is no parallel access to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not thread related, this code is basically broken:

```
int number = i;
char index[20];
sprintf(index, "%d", number);
char str[] = "unsorted_";
char str1[] = ".bin";
strcpy(str,index);
strcpy(str,str1);
```

Let's analyze it:

```
int number = i;
```

Why would you even do that? `i` is already an `int`. What purpose serves copying it?

```
char index[20];
sprintf(index, "%d", number);
```

Okay, you convert it to a string. You could just have used `i` directly here instead of `number`.

```
char str[] = "unsorted_";
char str1[] = ".bin";
```

Now you define two char arrays on stack and initialize them with string values.

```
strcpy(str,index);
```

And here is the first problem. You request that the content the pointer `index` points to is copied and the result of the copy is written to the pointer `str`. After this statement has executed, a new string exists in memory, it has the content of `index` and `str` points to it. This code is equivalent to:

```
char * temp = malloc(strlen(index) + 1);
memcpy(temp, index, strlen(index) + 1);
str = temp;
```

So `str` now has the same value as `index` and is no longer a stack pointer but points to dynamically allocated memory on the heap; which you never free by the way, so your code leaks memory.

Similar problem:

```
strcpy(str,str1);
```

This time `str1` is copied and then `str` will point to the copy. So in the end `str` is always pointing to ".bin", which means all files your try to create are named ".bin" (so in fact only one file is created and that file is hidden as files starting with a period are hidden on UNIX systems (use `ls -a` so see them).

A corrected version of the code may look like this:

```
const char * prefix = "unsorted_";
const char * extension = ".bin";
// Assuming that the number is never larger than 20 characters 
// as in your code. + 1 is for the terminating NUL character.
size_t filenameSpace = strlen(prefix) + strlen(suffix) + 20 + 1;
char * filename = malloc(filenameSpace);
if (!filename) {
    // Handle out of memory
}
if (snprintf(filename, "%s%d%s", prefix, i, suffix) == filenameSpace) {
    // Handle too little space! 
    // Apparently the number was larger than 20.
}
file = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR , 0666);
free(filename); // Don't leak memory!
```

On some systems this can be done much easier:

```
char * filename = asprintf("unsorted_%d.bin", i);
if (!filename) {
    // Handle out of memory
}
file = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR , 0666);
free(filename); // Don't leak memory!
```

But `asprintf` is no standard C function, it's a BSD extension and not available on all systems.